# Handling Generic Entities in Entity Framework's Change Tracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm implementing a Domain-Driven Design (DDD) architecture and want to leverage strongly typed IDs for my entities. My base `AggregateRoot` class looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId>
    : Entity<TId>
    where TId : struct
{
    private readonly List<IDomainEvent> _domainEvents = [];

    // ...
}
```

Here's an example entity:

```cs
public readonly record struct AuctionId(Guid Value);

public class Auction
    : AggregateRoot<AuctionId>
{
    // ...
}
```

I have a domain event dispatcher interceptor (`PublishDomainEventsInterceptor`) which I want to work generically with all aggregates:

```cs
internal sealed class PublishDomainEventsInterceptor 
    : SaveChangesInterceptor 
{
    // ...

    public async Task PublishDomainEvents(
        DbContext? context)
    {
        // ...

        // Problem: Need a generic way to handle strongly-typed IDs here
        var entities = context.ChangeTracker
            .Entries<AggregateRoot>() // Issue: Requires type argument
            .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
            .Select(e => e.Entity); 

        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I modify my `PublishDomainEvents()` method or related approach to make it work with `AggregateRoot<TId>` without knowing the specific `TId` type in advance? I want to maintain type safety and the benefits of strongly typed IDs.

Thank you in advance for your help, cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your interceptor code does not actually need to use the strongly-typed Id the easiest option would be to introduce a non-generic interface for `AggregateRoot<TId>` to implement and use it:

```cs
public interface IAggregateRoot
{
   IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> DomainEvents { get; }
}

public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId> : Entity<TId>, IAggregateRoot
    where TId : struct
{
    // ...
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var entities = context.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<IAggregateRoot>() 
    .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
    .Select(e => e.Entity);
```

Comment: @MaikHasler _"Or is the idea behind to still maintain the generic Entity with a strongly-typed ID and the interface AggregateRoot"_ - yes exactly, updated code to be more clear about it.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks! That's an awesome solution - Thanks!